# Что делает данный кусок кода?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

В общем, изучаю чужой код юзерскрипта, не корысти ради, а знаний для. 
 И попался вот такой кусок:

```
    nf : function (a) {
    var b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    g,
    f = " ",
    k = ".",
    h = 0,
    l = "";
    return 0 > a && (l = "-", a *= -1),
    isNaN(h = Math.abs(h)) && (h = 2),
    void 0 == k && (k =
            ","),
    void 0 == f && (f = "."),
    b = parseInt(a = (+a || 0).toFixed(h)) + "",
    c = 3 < (c = b.length) ? c % 3 : 0,
    g = c ? b.substr(0, c) + f : "",
    d = b.substr(c).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + f),
    e = h ? k + Math.abs(a - b).toFixed(h).replace(/-/, 0).slice(2) : "",
    l + g + d + e
```

И вот понять не могу, что он делает, кусок этот.

Периодически в коде попадались куски, которые использовали имена функций b, c, d, e,g , но они встречаются по несколько раз, и при том ничего внятного тоже не видно, каждый раз функции с этими именами имели разное назначение, что меня привело в замешательство.

Помогите разобраться, что делает эта функция. По надобности докидаю куски кода, либо дам полностью.

**Обновление**

Этот кусок лежит в самом конце скрипта. И вот если до него всё было более менее понятно, то с этим уже ужас какой то случился.
Оригинальный код вряд ли найти получится, т.к. этот же скрипт мне попадался только в обфусцированном виде.

Comment: Половина кода ничего не делает, вторая половина весьма извращенным способом разбивает число на разряды по три.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел, вроде.

[Ссылка](http://javascript.ru/php/number_format)

Answer (score 0):

Это код после минификации. Как по мне, так изучая такое скорее с ума получится сойти, чем что-то узнать.
Поищите оригинальный скрипт.